# Media next button in control strip?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, touch-bar

I was used to use the next key of my old MBP to quickly change the currently playing song.

I would like to know if someone knows a hack to get the next media button displayed directly in the control-strip.

I know I can access it with one more key press on the media (or expand) button.

Comment: Have a look at BetterTouchTool: https://www.boastr.net/ It let's you customize the TouchBar in many ways.

Comment: Thx, Yep this is a great tool, I use it extensively. However, it looks like, there is no support for customizing the control strip due to missing API.

Comment: Any updates/changes to this feature in 10.14 Mojave?